# what does "in the root directory of the source tree" mean?

Tags: python, installation

I am trying to install a package on Ubuntu. I think I have successfully done that using pip. The next step in the instructions says to run:

```
python setup.py install
```

"in the root directory of the source tree."

Can someone please explain what this last sentence means?

(The package happens to be "george").

---

Edit:

If I do:

```
pip show george
```

I get:

```
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Does this mean that the root directory of the source tree is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/george
```

If so, there is no file setup.py in that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the project top directory. There should be a setup.py file in that dir

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean the directory that contains all the files related to the package? Could you tell me how I find this?

Comment: Which installation procedure are you using, there are two options:
- pip: pip install george
- from source: https://george.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#installation

If you are using pip there is no need to run the setup.py

Comment: Oh I see! That makes sense. Thank you!